# C# PropertyBuilder: How do I set the value?

Tags: c#

I've created a property builder using `PropertyBuilder` (which is inside a type, built with TypeBuilder, and as you can guess is inside a Module. so on and so forth up to Assembly)

I would like to set the value of my property (specfically a `Dictionary<string,object>` in this case) after I just built it.  It has a `SetValue` method, but I'm getting thrown on the first argument (Object obj : object's value I'm setting).

Here's what I have:

```
Dictionary<string,Object> expectations = new Dictionary<string,object>();

PropertyBuilder builder = typeBuilder.DefineProperty("Expectations", 
                                PropertyAttributes.HasDefault,
                                typeof(Dictionary<string, Object>), null);
//builder.SetValue(???)
return builder;
```

Am I even in the right direction?

**UPDATE**

Ok, so SetValue's Object parameter is the object that holds the property of the value I'm trying to set.  However, although I've defined the property via `TypeBuilder`, it's not created (since you have to call `CreateType()` and instantiate it).

Long story short?  Define everything first, then create it, then assign values via `SetValue` using the created object as the first parameter.

Comment: Can you show the `builder.SetValue` that you've tried?

Comment: Have you answered your own question?  If so, please add it to Answers section & mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so SetValue's Object parameter is the object that holds the property of the value I'm trying to set. However, although I've defined the property via TypeBuilder, it's not created (since you have to call CreateType() and instantiate it).

Long story short? Define everything first, then create it, then assign values via SetValue using the created object as the first parameter.